# mysql console, keeps outputting garbled text if 'b' key is pressed

Tags: mysql, console

mysql -u username -p

mysql>

Now in the console whenever I press the <kbd>b</kbd> key the screen goes berserk with garbled text:

[image]

Google doesn't help here.

Edit: using ubuntu 12.10 with xterm or the default terminal

Output of mysql --version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
```

Comment: Just to narrow things down a bit, try using a different terminal emulator (e.g. `xterm` or `rxvt`).

Comment: Just tried xterm. Same effect

Comment: What's the output of `mysql --version`?

Comment: Added mysql --version output

Comment: Do you have anything strange in your `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` files?

Answer (score 4):

Problem Solved.

I had

```
bind '"\M-\e[C":forward-word'
bind '"\M-\e[D":backward-word'
```

in my ~/.inputrc . Removed it all is well now .
Thanks Evan